# Pass multiple keylists

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I want to create a macro that will draw a complex shape with several parts (like a circle and a rectangle):

```latex
\newcommand{\drawCircleAndRectangle}[1][]{%
    \draw[%my or default circle style props%] (0, 1) circle (1);
    \draw[%my or default rectangle style props%] (2, 0) rectangle (5, 2);
}
```

I want to specify keys for each part separately:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawCircleAndRectangle[%
        circle style = {red, thick},
        rectangle style = {blue, dashed}
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

That's what I did:

```latex
\newcommand{\drawCircleAndRectangle}[1][]{%
    \tikzset{#1}
    \draw[circle props] (0, 1) circle (1);
    \draw[rectangle props] (2, 0) rectangle (5, 2);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawCircleAndRectangle[%
        circle props/.style = {red, thick},
        rectangle props/.style = {blue, dashed}
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I don't like to specify `/.style` everywhere. Can I do it differently?

Comment: See also pic (chapter 18, page 262) and shape (section 106.5, page 1143).

Answer (score 2):

#### Adaptations

- use styles `circle` and `rectangle` to set the styles that are used (`circle props` and `rectangle props`)
- set these styles initially empty, so it also works, if you don't provide any parameter
- use own path for the command `drawCircleAndRectangle/.cd`

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    drawCircleAndRectangle/.cd,
    circle/.style={circle props/.style={#1}},
    rectangle/.style={rectangle props/.style={#1}},
    circle props/.style={},
    rectangle props/.style={},
}

\newcommand{\drawCircleAndRectangle}[1][]{%
    \tikzset{drawCircleAndRectangle/.cd, #1}
    \draw[drawCircleAndRectangle/circle props] (0, 1) circle (1);
    \draw[drawCircleAndRectangle/rectangle props] (2, 0) rectangle (5, 2);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawCircleAndRectangle[%
        circle = {red, thick},
        rectangle = {blue, dashed}
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This answer shows stuff possible via `expkv-cs` of which I'm the author. Nothing shown here is impossible to achieve with `pgfkeys`, but I think the `aggregate` keys are handy and something equivalent would need some extra work in `pgfkeys`. For more than this "play"-problem I'd probably build this using `pgfkeys` to not have to mix different key=value implementations.

The following uses `expkv-cs` to define your front facing macro. As a result you can't alter its basic behaviour via `pgfkeys`' interfaces. So this doesn't integrate as nicely into the typical `pgf`/Ti*k*Z interfaces. I've added the `\drawCircleAndRectangleSetup` macro with which one could alter the behaviour.

This defines a few extra keys for convenience. Those are the `+=` variants with which stuff can be added to the existing "styles", and `both` to set both `circle` and `rectangle` in one go. I also changed the behaviour to use every unknown key in both styles before the explicitly set keys.

(MWE stolen from [@dexteritas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/624365/117050))

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{expkv-cs}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\ekvcSplit\drawCircleAndRectangle@
  {
    % set the default styles here
     circle = {}    % will be #1
    ,rectangle = {} % will be #2
    ,...            % will be #3, contains every unknown key
  }
  {%
    \draw[{#3,#1}] (0, 1) circle (1);%
    \draw[{#3,#2}] (2, 0) rectangle (5, 2);%
  }
% define extra keys
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\drawCircleAndRectangle@
  {
    % `circle +=' adds stuff to the `circle' key
     aggregate circle += {circle}{#1,#2}
    % accept both circle+=<stuff> and circle += <stuff>
    ,alias     circle+ = circle +
    % same for `rectangle'
    ,aggregate rectangle += {rectangle}{#1,#2}
    ,alias     rectangle+ = rectangle +
    % add `both' and `both +='
    ,meta      both  = {circle= {#1}, rectangle= {#1}}
    ,meta      both += {circle+={#1}, rectangle+={#1}}
    ,alias     both+ = both +
  }
% add a macro to change the defaults
\newcommand*\drawCircleAndRectangleSetup{\ekvcChange\drawCircleAndRectangle@}
% wrapper for the optional argument
\newcommand{\drawCircleAndRectangle}[1][]{\drawCircleAndRectangle@{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \drawCircleAndRectangle
  \drawCircleAndRectangle[
    circle={green, dotted},rectangle={yellow, thin},both+=xshift=1cm]
  \drawCircleAndRectangle[
    circle={red, thick},rectangle={blue, dashed},yshift=-4cm]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]